# Finite additivity of a measure in the proof of Riesz representation theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading a proof of a version of the Riesz representation theorem and am stuck.

**Statement of Riesz representation theorem:** Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $L$ a linear functional on the set $C(X)$ of continuous functions $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies:

1. $L$ is continuous
2. If $f \geq 0$ then $L(f) \geq 0$
3. The indicator function on $X$ satisfies $L(\mathbf{1}_X) = 1$

Then there is a unique Borel probability measure $\mu$ with $L(f) = \int f \, d\mu$ for each $f \in C(X)$.

**The step that is troubling me:** First, $\nu$ is defined: if $C \subseteq X$ is closed,
$$
\nu(C) = \inf \{L(f): \mathbf{1}_C \leq f\}.
$$
And for general Borel subsets $A \subseteq X$,
$$
\mu(A) = \sup \{\nu(C): C \subseteq A \text{ is closed}\}.
$$
Then it is established that $\mu$ is the measure we are searching for. It is stated, but not proved, that $\mu$ is finitely additive. I could not verify this.

**What I could prove:**

1. If $C_1$ and $C_2$ are disjoint and closed, then $\mu(C_1 \cup C_2) = \mu(C_1) + \mu(C_2)$.
2. If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint Borel subsets, then $\mu(A_1 \cup A_2) \geq \mu(A_1) + \mu(A_2)$.

But why is the reverse inequality true, i.e., why is $\mu(A_1 \cup A_2) \leq \mu(A_1) + \mu(A_2)$?